# mongodb - $geoIntersects sorted by overlapping percentage

Tags: mongodb, polygon, geospatial, geo, polygons

I have a collection with this kind of documents:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  type: "string", // COUNTRY, STATE, CITY
  geometry: {
    type: "MultiPolygon",
    coordinates: <coordinates>
  }
}
```

And I want to calculate for example in which `COUNTRY` is every `STATE`. I've tried to do this:

```
var state = db.entity.findOne({_id:ObjectId("someStateID")});

db.entity.find({
  geometry: {
    $geoIntersects: {
      $geometry: state.geometry
    }
  },
  type:"COUNTRY"
});
```

And this works just fine, excepts in some cases where the line of some `STATE` is touching the border of a neighbour `COUNTRY` where I got two or more documents.

[Here is an example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci3fD.png)

Is there a way I can sort this result by overlapping percentage? Or any kind of filter to know which one is the exact parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that there is no way to do this in mongo, I had to do it with code. [Here is an easy way to solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455730/polygon-overlaping-percentage)